# How can I automatically clear logcat output before each run in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-logcat

I'm using Android Studio 1.0.2 and can't find the way to clear logcat output before each Run/Debug.

Is there any Gradle task (similar to `adb logcat -c`) that I can create a Run/Debug configuration for in order to clear output? Or is there simpler way to clear the logcat?

Answer (score 91, accepted):

This can be customized for each existing run configuration you have defined. Instructions for enabling this feature are given below:

#### Android Studio 1.4 and later

Check the checkbox located at:

> Run -> Edit configurations... -> Miscellaneous tab -> "Clear log before launch"

#### Android Studio 1.3 and earlier

Check the checkbox located at:

> Run -> Edit configurations... -> Logcat tab -> "Clear Log before launch"

Answer (score 2):

In Run menu select Edit Configuration
select your App configuration and in Log Cat tab check Clear log before launch.

Answer (score 2):

Android Studio 2.0: Run -->  Edit configuration --> Select your app --> Miscellaneous --> Clear Log before launch